# Why my Excel file does not open with PHP?

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I need to do data export in Excel file, I thougt so easy :)

I use PhpSpreadsheet library (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)

I try with PhpSpreadsheet samples and doing simple things :

1. create Xlsx Spreadsheet
2. Save on hardrive
3. Open in browser for download

There is my code :

```
require_once $this->config->application->libraryDir . 'PhpSpreadsheet-master/vendor/autoload.php';

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$fileName = 'export/hello_world.xlsx';
$writer->save($fileName);

// header('Location: '.$fileName);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$fileName.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

The result : The file was created on folder 'export', I can open it with Windows. 
But, when file is download on default folder of downloads, I can not open it. I have this error : Excel has encountered unreadable content

Have you an idea why this problem?

Comment: Maybe there is any difference in this two file?  I would compare size of these files in bytes as the simplest way.

Comment: @Gallyamov the is the same file ... I don't understand

Comment: Can you use `header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');` instead of yours? And try to remove first `$writer->save($fileName);`  (only for test)

Comment: if I remove $writer->save($fileName); it will be not possible to open a file which not exist

Comment: Try `exit`ing after `$writer->.save('php://output')`?

Comment: Prior to you `header(...)`s, try `exit`ing to make sure there is no output.

Comment: And since you know `$writer->save($fileName)` works, you could try, instead of calling `$writer->save('php://output')` you could do `$writer->save($fileName); header(...); echo file_get_contents($fileName);` Trying different content-types might be worthwhile too

Comment: @Reed it works with exit(); .... thanks

Comment: @user1450740, I posted my comments as an answer, since one of them did it. Glad you were able to get it working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `exit`ing after `$writer->.save('php://output')`. For troubleshooting, Prior to your `header(...)`s, try `exit`ing to make sure there is no output.

And since you know `$writer->save($fileName)` works, you could try, instead of calling `$writer->save('php://output')` you could do `$writer->save($fileName); header(...); echo file_get_contents($fileName);` Trying different content-types might be worthwhile too